# Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components

Tags: flutter

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 7):

configure your sdk path
`flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk`
 after that accept all the licenses 
`flutter doctor --android-licenses`
finally run 
 `flutter doctor`

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio open

Menu > Tools > SDK Manger

switch to tab "SDK Tools" and check "Android SDK Build-Tools"

click the OK button.

Comment: I am used android version 3.2 android 9.0 pie API level 28 all is updated, he is not find Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt to

Comment: The comments in https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/6772/could-not-find-aapt-exe might help.

Answer (score -2):

problems are slow

I just go on C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3
AND ADD aapt file.
and run command flutter doctor